# Script: Find duplicate filenames in two different directories

Tags: bash, macos, directory

I'm looking for files that end in ".jar" and using Mac OSX. This script must do a search strictly comparing dir1 to dir2 recursively since paths can change.

```
dir1 = "/apollo/pkg"
dir2 = "/apollo/env"
```

Let's say

```
jar1 = "/apollo/pkg/2/3/4/same1.jar"
jar2 = "/apollo/env/8/1/3/5/2/3/same1.jar"

jar3 = "/apollo/pkg/7/2/6/same2.jar"
jar4 = "/apollo/env/1/3/same2.jar"
```

I'm new to writing scripts and need to write a bash script that would result in echoing to cmd line

```
"/apollo/pkg/2/3/4/target.jar"
"/apollo/env/8/1/3/5/2/3/target.jar"

"/apollo/pkg/7/2/6/same2.jar"
"/apollo/env/1/3/same2.jar"
```

Please help.

Comment: What O.S are you using?

Comment: @michaelbecerra Mac OSX

Comment: To print file names which end with .jar you can simply run **find . -name "*.jar"** command under /Apollo folder.

Comment: Do you have permissions to read in that folders from command line?

Comment: @JohnFisherman - It doesn't sound like you are really *comparing* the directories, so much as looking for duplicate filenames that exist in either directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `find`, where you specify the place to start the recursive search (`'/apollo'`) and all `jar` files with `-name '*.jar'`.

```
find '/apollo' -name '*.jar' -print
```

Edit:
You could also try the command below, but it should be equivalent.

```
find /apollo -name *.jar
```

Comment: this doesn't print anything, i've updated my question

Comment: Could you please try `mkdir /apollo && sudo chmod u+rwx /apollo && touch /apollo/test.jpg` and rerun my command? It should work on Mac OSX. I'll add a variation in my solution to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linux, you could try something like this:

```
find /apollo -iname "*.jar"
```

If you want to search everywhere, try this:

```
find / -iname "*.jar"
```

Comment: this doesn't print anything, i've updated my question

Comment: Please, check that you have permissions to read on that folders. This command should work for MacOSX too.